# ASUS Q200E boots straight into BIOS

Tags: bios, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS Q200E running Win8 and it is booting straight into the BIOS. While there, the internal HDD can't be seen, and I also can't boot to a Linux installation from a USB drive. It's running an American Megatrends BIOS. There is no POST screen, no message, no BSOD, etc.

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Why can't you boot from USB or CD?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same model computer and after updating the bios I had the same problem. The solution for me was to disable the secure boot feature then everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

When you view the boot order in BIOS, is the hard drive listed at all? If not, I would turn the laptop off and reset the hard drive. It would also be a good idea to take the hard drive out and plug it into an external hard drive. Then you could try to connect it to a different computer which would let you know if it's dead.